# Compute the derivative of $R(y) = (2 \cos y - 3) /(\sin y)$

Tags: calculus

I know that the derivative of the function $\cos x$ is $-\sin x$, and the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$.

Given that, I thought the answer to the problem was: 
$$\frac{d}{dy} \frac{2 \cos y - 3}{\sin y} = \frac{2-\sin y}{\cos y}.$$

However, this answer is showing up as incorrect.
*What am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quotient of two functions of $y$. We must use something such as the quotient rule, or the product rule, or use trig identities in order to solve the problem. We have $$R(y) = \frac{2\cos y - 3}{\sin y} = 2 \frac{\cos y}{\sin y} - \frac3{\sin y} = 2\cot y - 3\csc y.$$ So, $$\begin{align}R'(y) &= {d \over dy}\left(2\cot y - 3\csc y\right)\\ &= -2\csc^2y+3\csc y\cot y \\&= \csc y\left(3\cot y-2 \csc y\right) \\ & = \frac{3\frac{\cos y}{\sin y} - \frac2{\sin y}}{\sin y} \\ &=\frac{1}{\sin y}\left(\frac{3 \cos y - 2}{\sin y}\right) \\ &=\frac{3\cos y - 2}{\sin^2 y}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of using the quotient rule first